# Spotlight not working fully for Recents - how to resolve?

Tags: finder, sonoma

Im working from a new MacBook Pro , 16" with Apple M3 Max chip.  Computer was set up a week ago using Migration Assistant and importing settings, user info, etc. from a 2019 MacBook Pro with Intel chip.  On older computer finder Recents worked fine displaying correct files according to selected search parameters - date added, date modified, etc.  When Finder was opened on old computer and Recents selected from sidebar , the results were correct and displayed almost instantly.

Not so on the new computer. When set up was complete and after a day or so of use, when Finder was opened and Recents selected from sidebar, no files were displayed.  I then went to System Settings, Siri & Search , Spotlight Privacy and added drive to be excluded.  Then closed settings and reopened setting to then remove drive from being excluded. This caused a re-indexing.  Finder then worked as expected.  I then shut down computer. The next day when I noticed files that were either created or modified failed to show in Recents under any search criteria.

I then made hard drive visible on desktop and went through the add drive to exclude search, but this time I dragged and dropped drive to spotlight search setting window.   I then closed out and reopened setting and removed drive so that it was once again included in searching.

After indexing, I then modified or created some files.  They failed to show in Recents when I open finder. If I have Finder open and Recents selected and search criteria of Date Added selected and I create a file, it will not show.  If I open Safari and download a file, it does not show right away either - I have to close and open Finder to make it show.  But, if I do a screen shot of desktop, it shows immediately in Recents.  Finder Recents is empty when I boot in Safemode.

Id like to know what else I can try to get modified or cleated files or downloaded files to show in Recents without having to close and reopen finder.

EDIT:  for instance , screenshot of file named RPSL - I created this file yesterday but if fails to show in recents list:

[image: RPSL]

In SafeMode

[image: Safemode]

EDIT - sorry....  I started MacBook Pro this am, 021624 , and added some files via scanning to desktop.  I also added a file to downloads via air drop.  I then opened Finder, selected Recents from sidebar and changed sort criteria and the new files do NOT show.  Sorry, I thought I had fixed it.

[image: new one]

[image: still missing 2]

[image: still missing 3]

Comment: so I am still trying too get this to work and have done a little more investigating.  Seems I need to get image files to show as documents & others do show.  Issue seems to be that image files on desktop will not show in Recents....

Comment: I was told by Apple support that what I’m experiencing is expected - Recents does not work like previous os  and is not suppose to display .jpeg on desktop. So now I wonder why they spent so much time troubleshooting with me  and why they show after being modified and why .png show???